# How to remove unnecessary newline in a string?

Tags: text-processing

I want to convert the text below:

```
I am "Ritesh
"|"Sil"
I am "Ritesh
"|"Sil"
You are not "Ritesh
"|"Sil"
```

Into:

```
I am "Ritesh"|"Sil"
I am "Ritesh"|"Sil"
You are not "Ritesh"|"Sil"
```

What will be the necessary shell script to implement this? In this case in each line there will be my name `"Ritesh" | "Sil"` ,i.e that is the only criteria. I don't want any newline to be inserted inside my name, like in this case there is newline after `"Ritesh`

Comment: please replace snapshots with actual text content! plus based on what criteria you want newlines to be deleted? Until a line start with uppercase? or line start with `"`?

Comment: In this case in each line there will be my name "Ritesh" | "Sil" ,i.e that is the only criteria.I don't want any newline to be inserted inside my name, like in this case there is newline after "Ritesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use GNU `sed`.

```
sed -z 's/Ritesh\n/Ritesh/g' infile.txt
```

For the `sed` if it doesn't have `-z` option.

```
sed '/Ritesh$/N;s/\n//' infile.txt
```

The `N` flag adding the **N**ext input line to pattern-space following a `\n`ewline delimiter when the current line ends `....$` with `Ritesh`. then next pasrt of the command `s/\n//` removes that delimiter.

Comment: There is no option like '-z ' for sed

Comment: please see updated answer

Comment: I have added explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would want to remove every second newline from a file:

```
awk 'NR % 2 { line = $0; next } { printf("%s%s\n", line, $0) }' file.in
```

or

```
paste -d '\0' - - <file.in
```

or with `sed`:

```
sed -e N -e 's/\n//' file.in
```

Comment: I think this is just for this example. From the description he wants to join all lines with a newline following `Ritesh`.

Comment: Let me try it..

Comment: `sed -e N -e 's/\n//' file.in` is also correct :)